# Is there a way to run an ASP.NET 1.1 web application completely self-contained (without IIS or SQL Server)?

Tags: .net, iis, .net-1.1

I have an ASP.NET application that we are currently hosting for an external client which is built with .net 1.1 running on IIS and SQL Server 2000. However, I don't want to host this application any longer and want to give it to the client so they can run it on their local machine. Is there a way that they can run this application on their local machine without the need for IIS? I've looked at this solution http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LightIIS.aspx but I'm not sure it works with .net 1.1. What's the best way to accomplish a locally hosted .net 1.1 web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not install IIS on the client's local machine?
If its OS is some kind of Windows Server, it has IIS installed anyway.
Even if it's a normal client machine - Win XP Professional comes with IIS out of the box.

Concerning SQL Server:
If your app doesn't use any special SQL Server features, you can try to use [MSDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSDE) (the Express version of SQL Server 2000) instead (download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=413744d1-a0bc-479f-bafa-e4b278eb9147&displaylang=en)).
If you **do** use features of the full SQL Server 2000, your client will need the full version on his local machine as well.

---

**EDIT:**

Now I'm reading your question again, and I'm thinking that I may have misunderstood the part about the client's "local machine":

Do you mean:

1. your client has one local machine
   ("local" as in "in his local
   network") that will serve the app in
   the future?
2. your client has no server, but one or more guys sitting in front of client machines...and each of these guys should be able to just copy your app on his local machine and run it from there?

When I wrote my answer above, I thought of the first case. If it's only one machine, then it should be no problem to install IIS and MSDE/SQL Server on it.

Or did you really mean the second case, running a complete copy of the app on each client?

Comment: I mean the first instance, where the client has just one machine that will run the app. I probably should have been a bit more clear in my original question. I'm trying to decide which route to go... I don't use features of the full SQL Server 2000 install, so the express version should work, however is this free, or would I need to purchase a license for this?

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: If your app only reads and writes data and does nothing special, you can probably use the newer SQL Server Express (MSDE is already deprecated because it's from 2000, and SQL Server Express is newer...and free as well).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an old skool article that talks about hosting the ASP.NET runtime. You might be able to make this work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188791.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. In the meantime, do you happen to know if I can't use the article I linked with .net1.1? I'd love to just be able to rule that possibility out instead of fruitlessly pursuing it (especially since I've already spent some time on it and I don't want to switch directions all of a sudden unless I'm sure...).

Comment: Even if you host it in ASP.NET 2, you can run a website built with .NET 1.1. The only requirement would be the 2.0 runtime on the client machine.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/index.htm). On the website they say it can host .net 1.1 applications. You can probably use ms sql express for the database.